# Textview not visible in Gridview with Image

Tags: gridview, textview, fragment, visible

I have a Gridview with 4 Columns and 2 Rows.

In the first row are Symbols and in the second row is the descripting Text (TextViews).

My Problem:
The Textview is not visible when i put it into the second row:

[image]

I have tried to change the color to something black but still not visible...

here is my Workdesk
[image]

The final **result** should look like: 
[image]

An Idea would be great!